# html <picture> displays properly in chrome but not in internet explorer 11

Tags: google-chrome, windows-explorer, images, html

I have an html page with a picture embedded in it using the code shown below:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="./images/myimage_small.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <img src="./myfiles_files/myimage_small.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

The folder `"./images/myimage_small.jpg"` exists in the server but `"./myfiles_files/myimage_small.jpg"` doesn't. If I understand [how  works as explained here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp), the browser should automatically show the picture that matches `media="(min-width: 800px)"`, and if it can't find a matching picture it will fall back to `img src`. In the code shown above, chrome displays `"./images/myimage_small.jpg"` correctly, while Internet explorer 11 attempts to display `"./myfiles_files/myimage_small.jpg"`, which doesn't exist so only displays a box with an `X`. Moreover, if `img src` is replaced by `"./images/myimage_small.jpg"`, it displays properly in both chrome and internet explorer.

Why is the current code working in chrome but not in explorer?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the current code working in Chrome but not in Explorer?

Based on the [browser support table for the `<picture>` element at Can I Use...?](https://caniuse.com/picture), it doesn't appear that `<picture>` is officially supported in IE 11 as of this writing (December 2020):

[image: Can I Use]

Comment: but then how does it work when both `srcset` and `src` point to `/images/myimage_small.jpg`? I thought unsupported in IE 11 meant the picture tag would be ignored or something

Comment: @user13267 ie will ignore the picture tag and just render the img tag.

Comment: @kicken so it's not that everything within `<picture>..</picture>` gets ignored, instead it treats the whole block of code as just `<img src="./myfiles_files/myimage_small.jpg" alt="">` because that's the only valid code it could recognise. Did I get it correct?